# Can a carrier of contradicting thoughts be called hypocrite?

Tags: ethics, terminology, meaning, cognitive-sciences

**Can a carrier of contradicting thoughts be called hypocrite?**

We know when people do/pretend something which he does not believe/poses, we call them hypocrite. Now what will happen if someone does not reflect his contradicting thoughts in practice? Can we still call him/her hypocrite. For example, If I believe everyone should be treated equally and at the same time I also contain hatred in my mind for specific religion follower. Am I a hypocrite then? Or I can be called hypocrite only if I reflect at least one of the thoughts as action in practice?

Note that, cognitive dissonance are usually unintentional but my question here is about an intentional contradicting belief.

Comment: "I believe everyone should be treated equally and at the same time I also contain hatred in my mind for specific religion follower" is not contradictory in the first place. Not unless the hatred is reflected in the treatment. There is a reason why hypocrisy label attaches to actions and not to mere emotions. Emotions can't be helped, they are not controlled the way actions are, there is no ordering the heart around. But one could, perhaps, attach the label to *willful* mental action, along the Jesus's line that to lust after a woman is to commit adultery in one's heart.

Comment: @Conifold isnt it a contradictory belief?

Comment: @Conifold what about holding two contradicting willful mental actions. Can we call a hypocrite to the holder?

Comment: "Contradictory" means logically incompatible, it is incompatible to do what one believes should not be done, but it is perfectly compatible to do what one hates. As they say rhetorically, I detest what you stand for, but I would give my life for your right to do it. I do not see how actions can be contradictory, but holding two incompatible beliefs, and acting on them, is intellectual inconsistency, not hypocrisy. Hypocrisy is about insincerity of behavior, not about irrational belief system.

Comment: Contradictory in the academic sense means a specific thing. That thing is a relationship between PROPOSITIONS. The term contradiction or contradictory DOES NOT & CAN NOT refer to actions. What you are expressing is the SLANG USE of the term. No logician will say somet action  is contradictory in a literal sense. The term is reserved for ideas not behaviors from those ideas. What you meant to say was A HYPOCRITE is the correct term for someone who says one thing but behaves in an INCONSISTENT WAY fron their  thought.  The correct term is hypocrite when you say X and you end up doing Y.

Comment: @Logikal you meant "The correct term is hypocrite when you say X and you end up doing ^X"?

Comment: No a hypocrite is a person who acts inconsistently with his or her actions specifically in English. For instance if I tell you that you should not smoke because smoking is hazardous to your health but you find out later on I smoke 3 packs of cigarettes per day. In this way I am saying X but I avoid doing X at the same time. If I tell you I am a smoker and then you see me smoke that is not a hypocrite at all. I would be acting consistently with what you know about me. Maybe you mean a person does X but really doesn't want to do X so there is resentment in his heart? That is doing X spiteful.